# How to Create Custom UIDatePicker Control

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad

I need to create Custom `UIDatePicker` Control Displaying Only Days of week,Hours,Minutes and time Format(Am,Pm). I had just started `iOS` development so not having so much of idea.Any insights or reference appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at the `datePickerMode` property of `UIDatePicker`

The different available modes are :

```
typedef enum {
   UIDatePickerModeTime,
   UIDatePickerModeDate,
   UIDatePickerModeDateAndTime,
   UIDatePickerModeCountDownTimer
} UIDatePickerMode;
```

If you need days of week, you will need to implement a basic UIPickerView and add your own data on it.

Comment: but I need only Week days, Time, TimeFormat

Comment: You can't do this with UIDatePicker. You will have to implement a basic UIPickerView and add your own data on it

Answer (score 1):

You need to create your own customized pickers using `UIPickerView`. If we want to to use `UIDatepicker`,

Need to use date picker mode as `UIDatePickerModeDateAndTime` and we need to over shadow the other data which is not necessary.